# Android: open multiple Text files from gridview

Tags: android, gridview, text-files

I just started into this Android development thing, by my own, basically reading various books and searching the internet and the forums for the information that i need, but it seems I got to a halt. I am trying to make an application by which the user will be prompted with a list of images in a gridview. Upon clicking an image, the application will sent the user to an activity which will display a, sometimes short, sometimes long, story that is read from a .txt file placed inside the assets folder. I can do it the easy way, ie. making an activity for each .txt that needs to be opened but i'm talking 50+ image files in gridview and 50+ .txt files in assets folder. So I want to do this from only 2 activities, main and +1, or as few as possible. below is the code i got so far.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById (R.id.gridv);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter (this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), ChronText.class);
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity (i);
        }
    });
}
```

}

ChronText.java

```
public class ChronText extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.flowtext);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

    TextView chronview = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.chronview);
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

    InputStream input;
    try {
        input = assetManager.open("");

        int size = input.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        input.read(buffer);
        input.close();

        String text = new String (buffer);
        chronview.setText(text);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context myContext;

public Integer[] myThumbsId = {
        R.drawable.breathingspace, 
        R.drawable.particletracks,
        R.drawable.welcomeparty,
        R.drawable.thebookofemptiness2of2,
        R.drawable.uplifted
};


public ImageAdapter (Context c) {
    myContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return myThumbsId.length;
}

public Object getItem (int position) {
    return myThumbsId [position];
}

public long getItemId (int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView (myContext);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(170,111));
    imageView.setImageResource(myThumbsId[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    return imageView;
}
```

}

The application works, however, I have to manually enter the filename in ChronText.java

```
        InputStream input;
    try {
        input = assetManager.open("");
```

so basically, i would need to manually write the filename for each image that is clicked. Is there a way this thing could be done automatically? And if yes, how? The way I am thinking is to make a list containing all the filenames, like the gridview has, that contains the files in the corresponding order of the gridview images, and when the user clicks the image, the activity is created for the file that has the same position in filename list as the image in the gridview list. If there is another, simpler way, please, do tell/explain. If my idea is good, please tell me how to put it 'on paper'. I worked on this app for some weeks now and i'm a bit burned out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After another week or so of head smashing, I have fount the answer and completed the app. I can show the result if anyone wishes to